# 'if' statement in jinja2 template

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to write an if statement in [jinja template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/):

```
{% for key in data %}
    {% if key is 'priority' %}
        <p>('Priority: ' + str(data[key])</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the statement I'm trying to translate in Python is:

```
if key == priority:
    print(print('Priority: ' + str(data[key]))
```

This is the error i'm getting:

> TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'string'

Comment: `is` should be used when comparing to a type, e.g. `if var is list`. In your case you want `key == 'priority'`.

Comment: @NicoleWhite In python the test `if var is list` does not check if `var` is a list ... it checks if `var` is the exact type `list` ... in `jinja2`, `if var is list` looks for a test named `list` ... which is unlikely to exist at all!!

Comment: Sorry, meant `type(var) is list`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Why the loop?

You could simply do this:

```
{% if 'priority' in data %}
    <p>Priority: {{ data['priority'] }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

When you were originally doing your string comparison, you should have used `==` instead.

Comment: I've downvoted for now, there is no need for the quotes around Priority, or the `str` inside the `{{ }}`.  i.e. it should just be `<p>Priority: {{ data["priority"] }}</p>`

Comment: worth adding minus after percent sign `{%- if 'a' in data -%}` to avoid empty lines

Answer (score 68):

We need to remember that the `{% endif %}` comes after the `{% else %}`.

So this is an example:

```html
{% if someTest %}
     <p> Something is True </p>
{% else %}
     <p> Something is False </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is the else statement necessary? cant it be just if then endif?

Comment: There is no mention of `else` in the OP.