# how to write custom message when specific item is not available in ansible_facts (say disk sdb is not available )

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am collecting some output from `ansible_facts` and writing them to a file on remote server with the help of copy module (content and dest)
I need to write as NONE if some item is not available on server (say disk sdb is not present on server).

How can I write NONE if disk `sdb` is not found?

My playbook is as below

```
- copy:
    content: |
      Memory = {{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}
      Size of disk sda =  {{ ansible_devices.sda.size  }}
    dest: /tmp/test
```

but if disk sdb is not available on the server how to check and write a custom message like below

```
Size of disk sdb =  NONE
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) filter. For example

```
- copy:
    content: |
      Memory = {{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}
      Size of disk sda =  {{ ansible_devices.sda.size  }}
      Size of disk sdb =  {{ ansible_devices.sdb.size|default('NONE')  }}
    dest: /tmp/test
```

Generally, Jinja2 condition `if-else-endif` should also do the job

```
- copy:
    content: |
      Memory = {{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}
      Size of disk sda =  {{ ansible_devices.sda.size }}
      {% if ansible_devices.sdb.size is defined %}
      Size of disk sdb =  {{ ansible_devices.sdb.size }}
      {% else %}
      Size of disk sdb =  NONE
      {% endif %}
    dest: /tmp/test
```

See ['if' statement in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620823/if-statement-in-jinja2-template/40620902).