# Ansible if else while iterating over a dictionary

Tags: ansible, openshift, prometheus

I have a dictionary of dictionaries collecting data from openshift using prometheus. Now I intend to add values in all the dictionaries. But some projects don't have quota and hence some pods don't have request/limit set for cpu and memory. I am trying the following and it fails in case the key:value is not there.

If possible I want to use if else such that, if the variable exists then add the variable else use the value as 0.

```
- name: Total section for Projects
  set_fact:
    pod_count_total: "{{ (pod_count_total|int) + (item.value.pod_count|int)}}"
    total_cpu_request: "{{ (total_cpu_request|float |round(2,'ceil')) + (item.value.cpu_request|float |round(2,'ceil'))}}"
    total_cpu_limit: "{{ (total_cpu_limit|float |round(2,'ceil')) + (item.value.cpu_limit|float |round(2,'ceil'))}}"
    total_memory_request: "{{ (total_memory_request|float |round(2,'ceil')) + (item.value.memory_request|float |round(2,'ceil'))}}"
    total_memory_limit: "{{ (total_memory_limit|float |round(2,'ceil')) + (item.value.memory_limit|float |round(2,'ceil'))}}"
  with_dict: "{{all_project}}"
```

Dictionary of dictionaries is like

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "openshift-web-console": {
            "cpu_usage": 0.015,
            "memory_used": 0.04,
            "cpu_request": 0.301,
            "memory_request": 0.293,
            "pod_count": 3
        },
        "srv-test": {
            "cpu_usage": 0.013,
            "memory_used": 0.02,
            "pod_count": 5
        },
        "test": {
            "cpu_usage": 0.001,
            "memory_used": 0.0,
            "pod_count": 1
        },
        "openshift-monitoring": {
            "cpu_limit": 1.026,
            "cpu_request": 0.556,
            "cpu_usage": 0.786,
            "memory_limit": 1.866,
            "memory_request": 1.641,
            "memory_used": 0.14,
            "pod_count": 98
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you add tag python? choose tag appropriately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['if' statement in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620823/if-statement-in-jinja2-template)

Comment: Example: https://gist.github.com/halberom/794c06598f40ccc31560

Comment: Documentation: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If possible I want to use if else such that, if the variable exists then add the variable else use the value as 0.

The thing you are looking for is [the `default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default)

```yaml
    total_memory_request: "{{ (
        total_memory_request | default(0) 
        | float | round(2,'ceil')
        ) + (
        item.value.memory_request | default(0) 
        | float | round(2,'ceil')
        ) }}"
```

There's a subtlety in that if the variable *exists* but is the empty string, you'll need to pass in the 2nd parameter to `default` to have it act in a python "truthiness" way: `{{ "" | default(0, true) | float }}` -- that might not apply to you, but if it does, you'll be glad to know what that 2nd param does