# I have a datefield field in mysql and how do I know if it is null

Tags: python, django

using django[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ddhb.png)

I want to create an if else block and make this data in mysql so that if it is empty, the button will not appear, but if it is not empty button will appear, I tried this, but it counts as full.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['if' statement in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620823/if-statement-in-jinja2-template)

Comment: You can post your view, html file, So others can help you

Comment: you can have do a check in your Django template.
{% if the_variable_sending_from_view  %}
    //show button
     <button></button>
{% endif %}